# Meaning of $J=-1$ in the energy eigenvalues of a two-body rigid rotor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

While studying the rotational dynamics of a two body rigid-rotor, the energy eigenstates of the system are described as $ E_J = B.J(J+1) $ having $ B = \frac{h^2}{8 \pi^2 \mu r_0^2}$ where $r_0$ is the separation between the two rotating bodies and $\mu$ is the reduced mass of the system.
In the lecture from where I was studying, it was stated that $J$ should be an integer and range from $0,1,2 ...$.

My question is that since $J=-1$ is also a valid solution for the $0$ energy eigenstate, why was it not taken as a possible value in the description of the eigenstates.
Also, if it indeed is a valid energy eigenstate, does that mean it is a degenerate state with the $J=0$ state? What would its wave function look like?
Thank you!

Comment: When we derive the eigenvalues of the angular momentum operator, the azimuthal quantum number has certain restrictions on it; its minimum value is $0$. That helps in keeping the wavefunction well behaved and finite everywhere.

Comment: Okay, could you forward some links which would help me understand this better? I am thinking that this would be an issue with the Legendre polynomials which are used to define the $\theta$ dependent part of the wavefunction. Thanks!

Comment: *J(J+1)* is the eigenvalue of angular momentum squared of a multiplet of dimension *2J+1*. The lowest dimension is 1, for *J=0*. There are *no* representations of negative dimension!! The fact that you could nullify this expression for negative *J* does not mean that SO(3) admits corresponding representations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I'm a bit unaware of the terms 'multiplet' and 'SO(3)'. Would you be able to provide some link explaining them better?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Quantization